# Creating a decorator for retries of a function

Tags: python, python-decorators

We have function example_2 which we would like to run. Sometimes it raises an exception, sometimes it doesn't.
Depending on the exception raised, I would like to log it(controlled exception) or not (uncontrolled exception). I would also like to retry the function example_2 a few times, only if the exceptions are controlled.

Here's my try (based on the book 'clean code in python'):

```
from typing import Optional
from collections.abc import Sequence
import logging
from functools import wraps

class ControlledException(Exception):
    """My own customized exception"""

class UncontrolledException(Exception):
    """An exception I don't like/control """


logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('tcpserver')

_default_retries_limit = 3
def with_retry( retries_limit =_default_retries_limit, list_allowed_exceptions = None):
    list_allowed_exceptions = list_allowed_exceptions or (ControlledException,)
    def retry (operation):
        @wraps(operation)
        def wrapping_function(*args, **kwargs):
            last_raised = None
            for num in range(retries_limit):
                print("Try number: {}".format(num+1))
                try:
                    return operation(*args, **kwargs)
                except list_allowed_exceptions as raised_exception:
                    logger.warning("returning %s due to %s",operation.__qualname__,raised_exception)
                    logger.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra=d)
                    last_raised = raised_exception
            raise last_raised
        return wrapping_function
    return retry

@with_retry(retries_limit = 5, list_allowed_exceptions = ControlledException)
def run_operation(task):
    print("Task result: {}".format(task))

def example_2(threshould_1,threshould_2):
    """random.random() draws from a uniform distribution"""
    print('Called example function')
    value = random()
    if value < threshould_1:
        print("value = ", value)
        raise ControlledException
    elif value > threshould_1 and value < threshould_2:
        print("value = ", value)
        raise UncontrolledException
    return value
```

When I call `run_operation(example_2(0.9,0.0))`, and when `ControlledException` is raised, nothing in the except branch of the try command is run... why?

Edit:

If I do

```
@with_retry(...) 
run_operation(...)
```

then I don't go to the except. But if I do

```
@with_retry(...)
example_2(...)
```

then I go to the except. Now I don't get why this should be different?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel here .. why not use a battle-tested third party library. I can recommend [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff).

Comment: @wim I'm just trying to learn how to do this. Thanks for the recommendation, though. ;)

Comment: At least in the example you posted, you are wrapping with `@with_retry` a function that doesn't throw a `ControlledException`. Shouldn't you be wrapping `example_2`?

Comment: @BorrajaX Hum... If I do @with_retry(...) ... run_operation(...), then I don't go to the except. But if I do @with_retry(...) ... example_2(...), then I go to the except. Now I don't get why this should be different?

Comment: because what is happening is that when python _sees_ this `run_operation(example_2(0.9,0.0))` it will call `example_2(0.9,0.0)` **first** (fully and completely) and theeeEEEeen it will (try) to pick up the result and call `run_operation` with whatever value was returned by the call to `example_2`. In this case, much before trying to run `run_operation`, the call `example_2(0.9,0.0)` has already thrown an Exception. Look at it like what'd happen if you did `my_result = example_2(...); run_operation(my_result)`  (in two lines). If `example_2` threw an exception, `run_operation` will not happen

Comment: @BorrajaX Many thanks for the patience. Write an answer, and I'll accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

Running:

```
run_operation(example_2(0.9,0.0))
```

is equivalent to:

```py
my_result = example_2(0.9,0.0)
run_operation(my_result)
```

If `run_operation` is "protected", but `example_2` can throw an exception (or... *does* throw an exception, rather), the "protection" provided by the decorator will never happen... Because `run_operation` will never be reached.

When Python *sees* this: `run_operation(example_2(0.9,0.0))` it will call `example_2(0.9,0.0)` first (fully and completely) and theeeEEEeen it will (try) to pick up the result and call `run_operation` with whatever value was returned by the call to example_2.

In this case, much before trying to call `run_operation`, the call `example_2(0.9,0.0)` has already thrown an Exception.